# add double quotes to a variable

Tags: linux, bash, variables, double-quotes

I have the following script and I need to have the variable $f surrounded by double quotes as some files have space in them:

```
# create a reftime (for the last 24 hours)
((reftime=$(date '+%s')-(24*60*60)))
# create a reffile for that time in /var/tmp (or any other place)
reffile=/var/tmp/reffile.$$.tmp
touch --date=@${reftime} ${reffile}

# find all files (in srcbase), that was changed in the last 24h - that means
# now all files that are newer then our reffile, and copy to destbase...
srcbase=/myorigin
dest=gpadmin@10.0.1.8:/mydest/dest

# for all of these files we need the directory names (because we need the structure for copy)
chgfiles=/var/tmp/chgfile.$$.tmp
find ${srcbase} -type f -newer $reffile 2>/dev/null | sort -u >${chgfiles}

cat ${chgfiles} | while read f ; do
 # echo "copy file $f to destination $dest ..."
  # create directory structures if not exist
  #mkdir -p "${dest}"
  # and finaly cp the file
scp "$f" $dest
done

# clear all tmp files
rm ${reffile} ${chgfiles}
```

I tried `scp "$f" $dest` but didn't work..

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, what would IFS be? sorry I'm not familiar with the term and kinda new to scripting

Comment: `read -d '' f` should accomplish the same as `IFS=` here

Comment: See [BashFAQ #20: How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) Also, there are a whole lot of other variable references that should have double-quotes around them. It's best to get in the habit of double-quoting *all* variable references unless there's a specific reason to leave the double-quotes off.

Comment: What is the error message ? Can you clarify "didn't work" ?

Comment: this dind't work: read -d '' f
It didn't get into the while

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) Probably check your script with http://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
scp "${f}" $dest
```

It added the doublequotes around the files that I needed.

I guess I was missing the {}

Comment: you beat me by a second to it :)

Comment: The braces make absolutely no difference here.